# Can we cut string in blogger template?

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I want to make string "baa" from "foo:baa" in blogger template, we know can add string `post.title + "baa"`, but how to cut string in blogger template?

Answer (score 0):

```
<b:eval expr='snippet(data:post.title, { length: 10 })' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with **operator extract** like so :

```
<b:eval expr='data:post.body snippet { length: 150 }'/>
```

But sadly, this operator mean to use for post body which of course ussually longer than a hundred character long. The length of character you can extract is vary from 50 to 1000 characters long.

Reference : https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/2017/04/operator-snippet.html